# Run function from Python 2 Tkinter button when pressed then run another when released

Tags: python, tkinter, pyaudio

Hello I am trying to make a simple recorder in Python 2.7 using Tkinter as the GUI, I want to be able to record when the button is pressed then save the recording when the button is released, I know how to make the button and have already done so, but I don't know how to make it run a program when pressed and another when released, is it possible?

Also I'm not sure how to actually record from the microphone and save it using pyaudio, any help with this is appreciated but I'm sure I can figure this out myself when I have overcome the main issue.

Comment: Ah okay thank you for the comment, how would I go about writing my own code for the button? is it worth the time or would I be better simply creating 2 buttons, one for recording and one for saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an event to the click of the left mouse button `<Button-1>` and to the release of the left mouse button `<ButtonRelease-1>`. Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def clicked(event):
    var.set('Clicked the button')

def released(event):
    var.set('Released the button')

var = tk.StringVar()
var.set('Nothing to see here')
label = tk.Label(root, textvar=var)
label.pack()

but = tk.Button(root, text='Button')
but.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
but.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", released)
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```